# Call to undefined function add_menu_page() on theme activation

Tags: theme-development, themes, errors, admin-menu, fatal-error

I am attempting to activate a theme that works perfectly on one WordPress install.  I have matched the plugins installed up and copied the theme over but when I go to activate it I get...

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_menu_page()
```

It points to the following line as being the cause of the error....

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'register_custom_menu');

function register_custom_menu() {
add_menu_page('Design', 'Design', 'delete_others_posts', '/nav-menus.php', '', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/tv.png', '5.1' );
add_submenu_page( '/nav-menus.php', 'Widgets', 'Widgets', 'delete_others_posts', '/widgets.php', '' );
add_submenu_page( '/nav-menus.php', 'Nav Menu', 'Nav Menu', 'delete_others_posts', '/nav-menus.php', '' );
add_submenu_page( '/nav-menus.php', 'Event Options', 'Event Options', 'delete_others_posts', '/admin.php?page=mytheme-options', '' );
}
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: If this code is inside a class, you might need to change `add_action('admin_menu', 'register_custom_menu');` to `add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'register_custom_menu' ) );`.

Comment: Where is this code? Can you post it in context?

Comment: Have you matched the settings of the other, working WP install? A poorly built theme may throw an error if its settings are not set appropriately (IE opting to use a sidebar/menu or something similar).

Comment: *I still cannot comment :( please don't down-vote* Could another plugin be calling your function, try changing the function's name, or wrapping `add_menu_page` in an `if(function_exists( "add_menu_page" ) )` statement.?

Comment: If the function already existed, it wouldn't throw a `Call to undefined function ...` error, but rather `Cannot redeclare ...`, no?! Am I missing something here?

Comment: that, is a very good point, unless the other one only declares the function if it is not already declared, doesn't harm to try :)